# If a virtual memory page is executable, does it imply that it is readable?

Tags: memory-management, x86, virtual-memory, page-tables

If I created a virtual memory page on a x86 system with the page protection set to only executable, would it imply that the page is also readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming IA-32e mode: yes, a page table entry has no bit that inhibits reading, only writing (bit 1, R/W).  Pages are always readable, assuming bit 2 (U/S, User/Supervisory) allows access.  Bit 63, EXB is the Execute Inhibit bit.  That's it for protection flags.  Chapter 3.10.3 in the Intel processor manual.

Answer (score -1):

I think the x86 doesn't have a seperate executable flag, all readable pages are executable.  So I guess that means the answer is "yes" (even if the logic is backwards).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit says that the executable flag/bit has been provided since P4 and also in the x86_64 architecture. So you are right for Intel processors older than the P4 and AMD processors before AMD64, but wrong for most x86 processors nowadays.